# How to prevent lazyloading of model property when assigning object?

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, variable-assignment, getter

I am trying to implement some lazy loading logic on a model on client side.

I tried to put the logic in the getter of these property but I realize now that when the object is created and assigned to a variable, it triggers all the getter of the property and thus trigger the lazy loading logic.

Model class :

```cs
    public class ProductStructure
    {
        public override Guid Id { get; set; }

        private List<AbstractStructureNode> subNodes;

        public override List<AbstractStructureNode> SubNodes
        {
            get
            {
                // Lazy loading logic including API calls to set subNodes
                return subNodes;
            }
            set
            {
                subNodes = value;
            }
        }
     }
```

API :

```cs
public async Task<ProductStructure> GetLightProductStructure(Guid Id)
        {
            if (Id == Guid.Empty)
                return null;

            string uri = ServiceUri + $"ProductStructures/Light/{Id}";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            Formatting = Formatting.None,
                            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                            SerializationBinder = new CustomJsonSerializer("R3.ProductStructureSDK.DataModel", "R3.ProductStructureSDK")
                        };

                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductStructure>(content, settings);
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The assignment that triggers the lazyloading (part of unit test)

```cs
ProductStructure LightProduct = await ProductStructureManager.Instance.GetLightProductStructure(RootId);
```

When a ProductStructure is downloaded from server, its subNodes is null. But the simple fact to assign the ProductStructure returned by the API to the variable 'LightProduct' will trigger the getter of subNodes. The API use async method so I cannot use ref.

Is there a common way to lazy load properties of an object ?

Comment: I don't understand the goal you're trying to achieve. What is, to you, the point of "lazy-loading" a model's property value ?

Comment: The subNodes property can contain hundreds of objects. When the application need to retrieve a ProductStructure it does not need its subnodes property immediatly. I simplified the code of the model, in fact it also contains a description string and other property which are the ones we need at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is an anti-pattern.

You're hiding IO / Api calls in your ProductStructure class.  A consumer would have no idea about the cost of those calls.

Unless you have a compelling reason for using the facade pattern (which is what you're implementing here) I'd break it down into two separate calls.

```
-> Product
-> ProductDetails
```

This will make your code cleaner and be much easier for developers maintaining your code to comprehend.

Comment: Ok so if I get it well the application will have to call for details by itself. I initially wanted the application to manipulate the model property directly without checking if it was set or not. I guess this is the anti pattern part you are talking about.

Comment: One more question if possible, how can I track if a model property has been already set. Particularly in cases where there is no data on the server and the property is null. I don't want to trigger API calls every time I detect the property is not set. Might be another question to post though.

Comment: Why do you need to? REST is stateless. You ask for the data - if it's present then display. If it's null then you already know there is no data on the server.

Comment: Incidentally, you'll want to create a service to wrap the HttpClient and hide all the JSON handling. Either that or create your own 'JsonClient' which does the same. You can avoid repeating a lot of code that way :)

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you deserialize your data with

`return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductStructure>(content, settings);`

then the hundreds of subnodes are created and loaded into memory. You can't lazy-load anything in ProductStructure for your scenario. 
What you should do is create a "LightProductStructure" class

```
public class LightProductStructure
{
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you need an object **without** the subnodes, deserialize the server's response using the LightProductStructure object. If you need it **with** the subnodes, then deserialize the server's reponse with the ProductStructureObject.

To make your code cleaner you should also refactor the ProductStructure object like this

```
public class ProductStructure : LightProductStructure
{
    private List<AbstractStructureNode> subNodes;

    public override List<AbstractStructureNode> SubNodes
    {
        get
        {
            // Lazy loading logic including API calls to set subNodes
            return subNodes;
        }
        set
        {
            subNodes = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

**Edit**:
Another way to do it without inheritence, would be -in some scenario- to store your subnodes as a string inside your ProductStructure object. This way you don't load hundreds of objects without the need, you just have a string in memory.
Then, when you need those objects call a method on your ProductStructure object that would deserialize that string, and assign the result to your Subnodes property. I think that's the closest you could be from the Lazy-load approach you're talking about in that scenario.

Comment: I get your point but because I don't want the server to include the subNodes every time I ask for a ProductStructure, I have several routes in the API. One of these (ProductStructures/Light/{Id}) already return a light product without the subNodes. The deserializatoin part is working fine and the object returned by GetLightProductStructure does not contain any subNode which is fine to me.

Comment: In that case, your method calling the "light" API should return a "light" object. Whenever you need to access the "full" object, make another call to the "full" API to retrieve your "full" object. Don't let that logic sit in your model. Handle these in a Business/Logic layer of your application. A Model should be a "dumb" data container with very simple logic

Comment: That sounds better indead, I'll have a thought about it